# Matrix multiplication using CUDA -- wrong results

Tags: cuda

I have following kernel code for matrix manipulation. Matrix A = 1*3 and Matrix B = 3*3 resultant Matrix C would be 1*3. In the following code the width would be 3.

```
__global__void MatrixMulKernel(float* d_M,float* d_N,float* d_P,int Width) {
   int row = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
   int col = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if(row>=Width || col>=Width){  // matrix range
      return;
    }
   float P_val = 0.0f;
   for (int k = 0; k < Width; ++k) {
   float M_elem = d_M[row * Width + k];
   float N_elem = d_N[k * Width + col];
   P_val += M_elem * N_elem;
  }
 d_p[row*Width+col] = P_val;
}
```

I kernel code is called as follows

```
int block_size = 32;
dim3 dimGrid(Width/block_size, Width/block_size);
dim3 dimBlock(block_size, block size);
MatrixMulKernel<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(d_M, d_N, d_P,3);
```

But I am getting wrong results. I am getting results as zero always.
Can anyone help me please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code looks likes its for multiplication of 2 square matrices of same size.

Width is the number of columns of the first matrix.

You have to provide this as an argument to the function.

Comment: Thanks. Yes indeed it is a square matrix. So block size 32 will not work properly for width = 300. as it is not completely divisible. So in that case I add 1 extra block to accommodate the remaining threads. Is that right ?

Comment: yes thats right, you would have to add extra block if width is not a multiple of 32.

but make sure you check in the kernel that the variables row and column are inside the matrix range.

this can be done like this inside the kernel:

`if(row>=Width || col>=Width)
   return;`

Comment: But when I change the size of matrix it gives me wrong results. Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: if you change the size of the matrix, then also change the grid size accordingly.  

Here is a simple trick to create a grid which works on any size of matrix:  

`dim3 dimBlock(block_size,block_size);  

dim3 dimGrid((block_size + Width - 1)/block_size,(block_size + Width - 1)/block_size);`